# navigation drawer icon size

Tags: android, navigation

I have set the icon of notification drawer for my AppCompatActivity using the code

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
this.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
this.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

But the custom image "ic_drawer" is a little too big for my liking. How do I set the size of the navigation icon.

I have already tried `<dimen name="homeAsUpIndicator">10dp</dimen>`
inside dimens file. That does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this For Fix :

```
<style name="Theme.white_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">64dp</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">64dp</item>
</style>
```

It worked!

*p/s : According to [Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar), define height matched the specification for the action bar icons, which is 32 x 32 dp.*

> mdpi   - 32 dp = 32 px
>
> hdpi   - 32 dp * 1.5 = 48 px
>
> xxhdpi - 32 dp * 2 = 64 px

use *3 *4 to xxxhdpi

- mdpi (Baseline):   160 dpi 1×
- hdpi:  240 dpi 1.5×
- xhdpi: 320 dpi 2×
- xxhdpi:    480 dpi 3×
- xxxhdpi:   640 dpi 4×

Please check the ic_drawer according to this size